# Pyspark: how to load online .gz log file into pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a .gz log file hosted online, like this

```
https://example.com/sample.log.gz
```

I can load this into a Python list using this:

```
import urllib2
from StringIO import StringIO
import gzip

request = urllib2.Request('https://example.com/sample.log.gz')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
buf = StringIO(response.read())
f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
data = f.readlines() # Python list
```

I then tried to convert this list to DataFrame using

`sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)`

but got

`TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'str'>`

What would be an effective way to load the .gz log file directly into `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` then?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the form of your `data` variable.
It is `['qwr', 'asd', 'wer']` but needs to be `[['qwr'], ['asd'], ['wer']]`.

To do so you can use `data = [[x] for x in data]`

Then `sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)`

---

Another solution could be to directly load your file as a textFile (however it requires to save the file somehow) then convert as presented above:

```
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
shutils.copyfileobj(response, f)
rdd = sc.textFile(f.name)
//save transformation as previously
rdd_list = rdd.map(lambda x: [x])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_list)
```

Comment: it works! but am also looking for other ways to load the .gz log into DataFrame directly